# Cookie Creation Time

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, request

Java version: 6

I want to be able to get the creation time of the a cookie through java. The API does not seem to offer any call through the HttpServletRequest object that would grab such data.

I know I could probably find a way to store the creation time in the hash value of the cookie but i would rather not.

Any ideas how i might be able to get the creation time?

Comment: It's not in API because cookie creation time is irrelevant, expiration time (max age) is what matters. If you really need to know when cookie is created you could use javax.servlet.http.Cookie.setValue() and pass creation time.

Comment: Yea storing it in the value looks like the only way to do it.